# Using pd.Series.dt.end_time produces different Timestamps than it should

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the series of datetimes

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2010-08-05']))
s

0   2010-08-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to create a series of period objects and get at the `end_time` attribute.

```
sp = s.dt.to_period('M')
sp

0   2010-08
dtype: object
```

Now, I access the `end_time` attribute.

```
sp.dt.end_time

0   2010-08-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I was almost satisfied until I realized that the `end_time` should be `Timestamp('2010-08-31 23:59:59.999999999')` and not `Timestamp('2010-08-31 00:00:00')`

Ok, so I compared

```
sp.iloc[0].end_time

Timestamp('2010-08-31 23:59:59.999999999')
```

---

```
sp.dt.end_time.iloc[0]

Timestamp('2010-08-31 00:00:00')
```

---

```
sp.iloc[0].end_time == sp.dt.end_time.iloc[0]

False
```

---

This makes no sense to me.  Clearly, the periods are correct.  How can I get `pd.Series.dt.end_time` to return the right thing?

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the period being set to 'M'... possibly.

Comment: If it had something to do with that, then why would `sp.iloc[0].end_time` produce the result I was expecting but `sp.dt.end_time.iloc[0]` not?

Comment: I'm not well versed with date questions... I usually avoid them like the plague, so please don't be too annoyed by my ignorance :p

Comment: Your uncomfortableness comes through in your interpretation that I'm annoyed.  On the contrary, I'm just keeping you on point (-:

Comment: Did you bug report this? Just looks like an inconsistency to me.

Comment: @Mitch yes I did.

Comment: @piRSquared Ahh and I just found it. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Issue reported on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17157) now